# How do I pass a data frame as an argument to a function?

Tags: r, function

T12 is a data frame with 22 columns (but I just want column 2 till 8) and about one million entries.
Some of the Entries are NA in column one. Everytime there is NA in first column, complete cases deletes the complete row. Everything works well.

I Have a lot more data frames and I don't want to write the whole code again for every data frame.

I would like to have something like this function and want to put as x T12, T13, T14, T15 and so on.

Might you help me?

```
split <- function (x){
  x <- x[,2:8]
  x <- x[complete.cases(x[ ,1]),]
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

- If you have dataframes named `"T12"`, `"T13"` etc, you can use the pattern `"T"` followed by a number to capture all such dataframes in a character vector using `ls`.
- Using `mget` you can get dataframes from those character vector in a named list.
- You can then use `lapply` to apply `split` function on each list.

```
new_data <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern = 'T\\d+')), split)
```

`new_data` has list of dataframes. If you want these changes to reflect in original dataframe use `list2env`.

```
list2env(new_data, .GlobalEnv)
```

PS - `split` is a default function in R, so it is better to give some different name to your function.

Comment: These data.frames should be put into a list when they are created. Code would be much easier and cleaner if you remove the need for `mget` or similar approaches. Using `list2env` like this is not the use case intended by its creator. It's also never necessary.